# Method 'Names' of object '_Application' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble deploying an Excel 2010 spreadsheet with VBA to a client. They are reporting the following error: "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Names' of object '_Application' failed".

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

The relevant portion of code where it is failing is as follows:

```
Dim settings as Range
Set settings = Application.Names("basictags").RefersToRange
```

The name "basictags" definitely exists in the spreadsheet (and it works fine on my end), so I am thinking it has something to do with protected mode being enabled on the client's end. However, they have confirmed that they hit the "enable" button when the protected mode warning is displayed by Excel, so I'm not sure what else could be causing it.

Comment: It's really strange that it would report "_Application". The underscore means that you didn't qualify the reference, like you used `Names("basictags")` without the Application qualifier and it had to use the default parent for Names. But the default parent is Workbook, not Application. Name problems are usually scope related, but I could reproduce this one.

Comment: It seems as though this instance of Excel doesn't like the global namespace... qualifying with ThisWorkbook as suggested by dotNet fixed the original error, but now using Sheets() call, the client reports "Method 'Sheets' of object '_Global' failed"

Answer (score 4):

Try `Application.ThisWorkbook.Names` instead of `Application.Names`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error, but can you explain why? My client is reporting similar errors now trying to use the Sheets() function.

Comment: `Names` corresponds to the __named ranges__ of the workbook, a functionality that is available directly in Excel too (that you can select a range, define a name for it and then later use that name in your formulas instead of range address). So you can imagine that in the Object Model, this property should logically be part of the `Workbook` object and not the `Application` object.

Comment: @user2312119: When an answer works for u, accepting it will help not only the answering buddy but also the future visitors.